# libavdevice.so.57: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied"

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have successfully installed ffmpeg ver. 4.4.7 on centos, with shared enabled as such :

```
[root@localhost ~]# ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-81555-g496d97f Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 29.100 / 55. 29.100
  libavcodec     57. 54.102 / 57. 54.102
  libavformat    57. 48.102 / 57. 48.102
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 60.100 /  6. 60.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

However, when I run in php, through exec I get

> "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libavdevice.so.57: failed to map segment from shared object:
>   Permission denied"

I know the web server executes the command as user 'apache' and not root, but I installed ffmpeg in /usr/local/ffmpeg_build for that specific reason, so that the regular users can use ffmpeg.

What did I miss? What does this error mean?

Comment: Does the user `apache` know of the /usr/local/ffmpeg_build path?

Comment: How can I know if it "knows" it or not ?

Comment: I've changed the ownership of the /usr/local/ffmpeg_build to apache with 777 permission just to try, and then restarted apache with no luck, still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found the answer on this link 
http://www.idmworks.com/fix-failed-map-segment-shared-object-permission-denied/

Turns out to be SElinux on Enforcing mode not Permissive, it started to work as soon as I set it to permissive mode.

```
$ getenforce
Enforcing
$ sudo setenforce 0
$ getenforce
Permissive
```

To make it permanent

```
 vi /etc/selinux/config
```

and change enforcing to permissive

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```