# Running Rscript from within PHP: cannot load shared libraries

Tags: php, r, apache, rhel, rscript

I am trying to run R code from within PHP. I am using RHEL 7.4.

However, because Apache runs as a different user than installed the R packages, it cannot load packages:

My PHP code has this line:

```
echo shell_exec("(Rscript -e 'library(lme4, lib.loc = \"/var/www/R/lib\")')2>&1");
```

which produces this error in the browser:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'lme4' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/var/www/R/lib/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /var/www/R/lib/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
Execution halted
```

The file `/var/www/R/lib/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so` has permissions 775, so I don't think the permissions are actually the problem.

How can I tell Apache / PHP where to look for the shared libraries?

The server is not public-facing, so I would take any solution from properly accessing the shared library, to giving user `apache` sudo access with `NOPASSWD` to run as my user (or something similarly reckless, since that didn't actually work...).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This appears due in part to an SELinux setting in Red Hat. I'm not entirely sure whether this is Red Hat-centric, or specific to the configuration at my university (who installed Red Hat in the first place).

Originally:

```
$ getenforce
Enforcing
```

Fix:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
$ getenforce
Permissive
```

Persistent fix: modify `/etc/selinux/config` to have the line

```
SELINUX=Permissive
```

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424704/libavdevice-so-57-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-permission-denied) StackOverflow thread.